# Is there an action_filter hook to add content before the post title?

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I am looking to add content before the post title but not included in the markup of the title itself so adding to `the_title` doesn't seem to be the right hook for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no reliable hook. The markup is provided by the theme, and there unlimited variants. You will have to change the theme’s markup directly.

Comment: hmmm, not the answer I was looking for :)

I'm looking to have the plugin operate totally independently to the theme so it looks like it's back to the drawing board.

Thanks,
K

Comment: Why can't you use `the_title` filter and just prefix your markup?

Comment: @KDM Because you cannot break out of a `<h1>` without creating some orphaned markup.